# Isomorphism between a vectorial space and its dual using bilinear forms.

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

If $g$ is a non degenerate symmetric bilinear form over a v.s. $V$ of finite dimension I want to find an isomorphism between $V$ and its dual in the more natural way possible.

I thought about defining $\phi:V\to V^{*}$ by $\phi(x)=g_{x}$ where $g_{x}(y)=g(x,y)$. I proved that $\phi$ is linear transformation and is injective but i don't know how to prove that it is surjective.

Now that I'm thinking, could I use the fact that $\dim(V)=\dim(V^{*})$ so then $\phi$ is isomoprhism? Or maybe I defined my $\phi$ in a wrong way

Comment: Choosing a basis $B$ and then showing $\{\phi(v)\}_{v\in B}$ is a basis via your dimension idea would work. Though there may be a basis-free proof. For that, you might be able to define an function $V^* \to V$ and show that it's an inverse. It may be doable with the canonical pairing between the vector space and its dual. $\alpha(x) = <\alpha, x >$.

Comment: Yes, $\dim V=\dim V^*$ due to finite-dimensionality, so a linear mapping is injective if and only if it is surjective if and only if it is bijective (because of the rank-nullity theorem).

Comment: Alternatively, one could prove that $\phi$ is surjective in the same way that one would prove the Riesz representation theorem